# How to Create a Streamlit Dashboard with State Persistence in JSON?

Tags: python, design-patterns, software-design

I'm working on a `Streamlit` dashboard project where I need to save the state of the application, including various parameters and behaviours, in `JSON` format. The goal is to ensure that when users interact with the dashboard and make changes to parameters, those changes are automatically serialized into `JSON` and saved. When the dashboard is refreshed or revisited, the state should seamlessly load from the `JSON` file

Here's the Python example I'

```
m currently working on:

python
Copy code
import os
import json
from typing import List

from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator

STATE_PATH = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'crop_state.json')

class SelectCameraState(BaseModel):
    selected_cameras: List[str]

class CropState(BaseModel):
    crop_type: str  # Anchor / Fixed
    bbox: List[int]
    anchor_class: str
    anchor_position: List[int]

class ProcessState(BaseModel):
    feature_extractor: str
    embedding_processor: str
    outlier_detector: str

class ApplicationState(BaseModel):
    camera_select_state: SelectCameraState
    crop_state: CropState

    class Config:
        validate_assignment = True

    @root_validator
    def update_property(cls, values):
        with open(STATE_PATH, 'w') as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(values))

a = ApplicationState()
a.camera_select_state = SelectCameraState()
a.camera_select_state.selected_cameras = ["blah"]
```

However, I've encountered some issues with this approach:

When using `Pydantic` models, changes to mutable objects like lists are not automatically recognized by the root validator, leading to problems in saving the state.

This approach doesn't align with conventional patterns for state management in `Streamlit` applications.

I'm seeking guidance on how to implement state persistence in a `Streamlit` dashboard more effectively and conventionally. I'm open to suggestions for design patterns, libraries, or techniques that can help me achieve state persistence in `Streamlit` while accommodating changes to mutable objects and maintaining clean, organized code.

Any advice, code examples, or best practices for handling state persistence in `Streamlit` would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would not use json dumps, since pydantic has serialization build in. Also it seems you are misusing the validator to store the state? I would not recommending doing that.

Comment: Thank you for your insights. I'm exploring design patterns for automatic state saving to disk on parameter changes. Could you elaborate on which pattern might be best for this? Also, when advising against JSON dumps, are you suggesting the use of Pydantic's .json() method for serialization?

Answer (score 0):

The pydantic function you want is [`model_dump_json()`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/serialization/#modelmodel_dump_json) (at least in the newer pydantic versions).

An example to write to a json file could look like this:

```
with open("applicationstate.json", "w") as jsonfile:
    jsonfile.write(applicationstate_model.model_dump_json(indent=2)
```

[Streamlit already has a built-in session state for multi-page applications](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/session-state#serializable-session-state) - you could use that as well, or simply use your own model. Anyway, have a look at the sections in the linked doc about callbacks. Basically, you can write your function to write your state to serialized and fire it using the `on_change` event:

```
import streamlit as st

def save_application_state():
    with open("applicationstate.json", "w") as jsonfile:
        jsonfile.write(applicationstate_model.model_dump_json(indent=2)

applicationstate_model = st.toggle('Activate feature', on_change=save_application_state)

if on:
    st.write('Feature activated!')
```

I haven't tested the code above but it should at least get you started.